# IServerXMLHTTPRequest vs WinHTTP Performance

Tags: xmlhttprequest, winhttp, serverxmlhttp

I am trying to compare IServerXMLHTTPRequest and WinHTTP in regards to performance.

I would like to know:

1. What is the maximum limit of the data/file that can be sent?
2. What is the transfer rate if the file to be sent is the maximum limit?

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be needing an information about this.

IServerXMLHTTPRequest is a thin layer above WinHTTP. Being a layer over WinHTTP means SXH will carry additional overhead. SXH doesn't provide any additional functionality over WinHTTP, other than the ability to directly support XML Document objects. [source](http://microsoft.newsgroups.archived.at/public.inetsdk.programming.wininet/200401/0401213170.html)

And thus by using the WinHTTP object directly you achieve higher performance, scalability, and reduced memory consumption. [source](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?147240-Powerful-MS-HTTP-request-component-alternative-to-ServerXMLHTTP!)

If you are dealing with very large payloads (either posting/receiving multi-megabyte requests/responses), then use the WinHTTP Win32 API. The SXH component does not handle large data payloads efficiently--it will store all the data in a single memory buffer. The WinHTTP Win32 API allows the application to send/receive data using separate, smaller memory buffers. [source](http://microsoft.newsgroups.archived.at/public.inetsdk.programming.wininet/200401/0401213170.html)